Query Regarding Use of Visitor (Subclass 600) Business Visitor Stream Visa
I am writing to seek clarification regarding the use of my current Australian visa. The details of my visa are as follows:

Visa class/subclass: FA / 600
Visa stream: Business Visitor
Visa grant date: 01 August 2024
Visa expiry date: 01 August 2025
Entries allowed: Multiple entries

I originally obtained this visa to attend a conference in Australia. However, due to other commitments, I was unable to attend at that time. I now plan to visit Australia for 4-5 days during the New Year period and to visit family friends.
Given that my visa is in the Business Visitor stream, I would like to confirm:
Am I eligible to use this visa for a short personal visit, even though I do not have any business activities or conferences to attend?
Are there any specific conditions or restrictions I should be aware of for this type of visit?

Welcome to TSE. What has your own research on this topic revealed so far? Eg have you checked the visa conditions? What did the visa issuing office say when you contacted them?

@Traveller, In my visa, they have stated the work-related conditions. They haven't mentioned anything about the tourist activities or meeting with family members. However, I came across a website called "Visa Envoy": "https://visaenvoy.com/visitor-visa-subclass-600/business-stream/" Where they mentioned that you are allowed for these activities. Also On reddit I saw a person post a screen shot of the email which she received from the Australian embassy in Manila stating that on this business visa you can undertake tourists activities."

Any business visitor visa typically allows tourist activities. The question you need to resolve, IMHO, is whether your unused visa is valid for a completely different purpose to that for which it was originally issued. Some countries frown on that, IDK about Australia. Personally, if I were you, I would contact the issuer, rather than rely on extrapolating the opinions/experiences of random internet strangers to your own personal situation.

See https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/see-your-visa-conditions#
Select "Visitor (sub-class 600) Business Visitor"
Conditions
"The holder must not work in Australia other than by engaging in a business visitor activity.
You can:

make general business or employment enquiries
investigate, negotiate, sign or review business contracts
undertake an activity of an official government-to-government visit
participate in conferences, trade fairs or seminars in Australia—but the organisers must not pay you for taking part

You must not:

undertake work for, or supply services to, an organisation or other person based in Australia
sell goods or services directly to the general public"

My reading of this is that you can do any "normal activity" and as well you can do the things that are specified by "You can", but you must not do the things specified by "You must not". I suggest normal activity includes visiting family and friends.
The visa you have been granted is current for 12 months even though you applied based on a single conference, which would not run for 12 months. It could be deduced that the Department of Immigration when granting the visa, expected you to travel to Australia for other reasons than attending that conference during the validity of the visa.
